# Feign pageable sort is not consumed by controller

Tags: java, spring, serialization, feign

I use feign to make request to another microservice.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/orders/search")
    AbstractResponse<Page<OrderResponse>> searchOrders(Pageable pageable);
```

It results in calling

```
GET http://localhost:8090/orders/search?page=0&size=5&sort=id&sort=DESC
```

However, spring controller

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseWrapper<Page<OrderResponse>> searchOrders(@PageableDefault(sort = "id", size = 5) Pageable pageable) {
```

Seems to not pay attention to second sort=desc and sets order to default(ASC)

When trying to do query manually like

```
GET http://localhost:8090/orders/search?page=0&size=6&sort=id,desc
```

It worked as expected(when using sort=id,desc)

How to make feign client send pageable requests that are supported by the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding
`@CollectionFormat(feign.CollectionFormat.CSV)`
to feign query, like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/orders/search")
@CollectionFormat(feign.CollectionFormat.CSV)
    AbstractResponse<Page<OrderResponse>> searchOrders(Pageable pageable);
```